# Gson Serializer for a given class if in another specific class

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I am trying to serialize (using Gson) a POJO and to have a special treatment for a single one of its fields.

Is it possible to do it in a simpler way than coding an adapter implementing `JsonSerializer` and having its `serialize()` method copy every field except for a specific one which receives the special treatment ?

Would it even be possible to make it using annotations in my POJO ?

I also cannot just write an adapter of the type of the specific field as it is a `java.util.Date` and I do not want every serialized Date to receive this treatment.

---

Here is an illustration :

```java
public class Pojo {

    @SerializedName("effectiveDate")
    private final Date mDate;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private final Status mStatus; // <-- The field needing specific serialization

    @SerializedName("details")
    private final String mDetails;

    // other fields

    // methods
}
```

I would like to avoid coding an adapter as such :

```java
public class PojoAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Pojo> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(final Pojo src, final Type typeOfSrc, final JsonSerializationContext context) {
        final JsonObject jsonPojo = new JsonObject();
        jsonDeployment.add("effectiveDate", /* special treatment */);        
        jsonDeployment.add("status", src.getStatus());
        jsonDeployment.add("details", src.getDetails());
        // other fields setting
        return jsonPojo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement custom `com.google.gson.JsonSerializer` for a `Date` class and use `com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapte` annotation for given field to register it. See below example:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;
import com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(new DatesPojo(new Date())));
    }

}

class CustomDateJsonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        String format = src.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME);
        return new JsonPrimitive(format + " ISO TIME");
    }
}

class DatesPojo {

    @JsonAdapter(CustomDateJsonSerializer.class)
    @SerializedName("customDate")
    private final Date mDate0;

    @SerializedName("effectiveDate")
    private final Date mDate1;

    public DatesPojo(Date mDate) {
        this.mDate0 = mDate;
        this.mDate1 = mDate;
    }

    public Date getmDate0() {
        return mDate0;
    }

    public Date getmDate1() {
        return mDate1;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "customDate": "22:37:21.806+01:00 ISO TIME",
  "effectiveDate": "Jan 22, 2020 10:37:21 PM"
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for ! Thanks @Michał Ziober

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution which consists in making my `Date` field implement an `EffectiveDate` interface which just extends `Date` and to add an adapter for this single field.